# How to pass variables into SQL query using Jupyter Notebooks Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

For Example:

```
%bq query -n qu

SELECT 

    *

FROM

    Table

WHERE 

    [passed in variable (column)] = true
```

Then i want to execute the query in a loop

```
for row in data:

  bq.execute qu(row[1])
```

Does something along these lines exist?

EDIT: I figured out a solution for anyone who comes across this question

```
For row in [dataset with your variables]:

   query = "SELECT * FROM DATASET WHERE {} = TRUE".format(variableData[0])

   tab = bq.Query(query)

   df = tab.execute(output_options=bq.QueryOutput.dataframe()).result()

   qu = [list(x) for x in df.as_matrix()]

   print(qu)
```

Comment: Why would you want to execute the query in a loop, rather than pass all the variables into a single query?

Comment: I need say, 500, different sql statement executions. When one variable is true, then print results, then a different variable true, etc

Comment: Can you pull all the data in one query, and then iterate through the result?

Comment: No, because each query needs to be filtered a certain way. I figured out a good solution and will edit my question

Answer (score -1):

Here's a complete example showing Python variable substitution.
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=0B7I8C_4vGdF6Mk1RMm1Fdm9EQVU

The notebook shows the following:

1. Create a BigQuery table from some random CSV data.
2. Query that table using the Pandas GBQ connector.
3. Construct and execute a query against that table using Python variable substitution.